# Find a subgroup of index 3 of dihedral group $D_{12}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Find a subgroup of index 3 in the dihedral group $D_{12}$. I know the number of elements in $D_{12}$ is 24 and also that is we have this subgroup of index 3, then we obtain that $|D_{12}:H|=8$, where $H$ is our wanted subgroup, but I don`t know how to go further.
I am new to this type of problems and I do not have many examples, could you provide a full proof, or at least in the form of an answer, such that it would serve as a model for similar problems I encounter? Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Can you find a subgroup of index $3$ in $D_3$? in $D_6$? You should work these out for yourself first.

Comment: I don`t know how to find them because I am not used with this notion. Please, help me have an example!

Comment: You can think of $D_{12}$ as the set of rotations and reflections of a regular $12$-gon. What are these rotations/reflections? What are their orders as group elements?

Comment: The group $D_3$ has only six elements: spend an hour or two playing with them until you find a subgroup of index $3$. That will do you more good than copying down a solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$D_{12}$ is generated by $a,b$ with $a^2=b^{12}=1, aba=b^{-1}$. Then $b^3$ generates a subgroup $A$ of order $12/3=4$. That subgroup is normal in $D_{12}$ because $ab^3a=b^{-3}=b^9=(b^3)^3$. Then $a$ and $A$ generate a subgroup $H$ of order 8. The index of that subgroup is then 3.

Comment: Could you write please all its elements? Then I would accept it, thank you!

Comment: It has elements $b^3, b^6; b^9, 1, ab^3, ab^6, ab^9, a$.

Comment: Thank you! Could you help me with this, please? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3749483/prove-that-u-21-is-isomorphic-with-mathbbz-21?noredirect=1#comment7710942_3749483

Comment: That question does not exist.